# Sending email after two weeks from registration date

Tags: php, mysql, date, cron, timestamp

I have a php script that immediately sends an email when a user fills in an online form.
However, I want the user to get the email after 2 weeks from submitting the online form.
How can I implement that in PHP (code).
Thank You in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup cronjob on server for this purpose.

Comment: How exactly implement that? cronjob

Comment: Which server you are using for your code? Linux or Windows?

Comment: I am using linux, sir